# Artisan output returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using `Artisan::output();` it return `""` this in Laravel 5.4. How can I fix this ?

My code:

```
Artisan::call('backup:run');

 $output = json_decode(Artisan::output());
```

Comment: Try like: `dd(\Artisan::output());`

Comment: it return   " "  this

Comment: You can use it like: `$command = 'backup:run';

$params = [
        'data' => $request->get('date'),
];

Artisan::call($command, $params);
dd(Artisan::output());` Like  this you can use artisan output as i understand and used.

Comment: Can you post or link the code used in the command behind backup:run?

Answer (score 1):

As i suggest in my comments, i'll posted my answer here to get idea for other users!

You can use it like:

```
$command = 'backup:run'; 
$params = [ 'data' => $request->get('date') ]; 
Artisan::call($command, $params); 
dd(Artisan::output());
```

Like this you can use artisan output as i understand and used.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

\Artisan::call('backup:run');

$output = json_decode(\Artisan::output());

Please, \ used for global access.

Comment: it returns null